# Разбить список на пары и каждую пару объединить"_"(нижним подчеркиванием)

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, текст

Есть список в виде:

> items = [5, 80, 3, 83, 1, 77, 1, 77, 2, 82, 1, 77, 5, 81, 2, 78, 1, 81, 5, 85,
>   5, 85, 4, 84, 2, 78, 1, 81, 3, 83, 3, 78, 2, 82, 3, 83, 2, 78, 5, 85,
>   5, 81, 2, 82, 4, 84]

Как разбить его на пары и каждую пару объединить "_" (нижним подчеркиванием) ?

Желаемый результат: 5_80, 3_83, 1_77, 1_77 и т.д.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример с ожидаемым результатом и ваши наработки (это поможет)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new_items = ['{}_{}'.format(items[i], items[i + 1]) for i in range(0, len(items), 2)]
print(new_items)  # ['5_80', '3_83', '1_77', '1_77', '2_82', '1_77', ...
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! Все работает!!! Ответ отметила

Comment: @Ireen1985, спасибо что приняли ответ, но думаю вы немного поторопились с этим :) думаю, в течении дня, появится еще пара вариантов от других участников ;)

Comment: Да, Вы правы, такое возможно, но меня этот вариант вполне устроил

Answer (score 6):

В случае, когда стоит задача обойти коллекцию по блокам фиксированной длины, может быть полезна следующая конструкция `zip(*[iter(collection)] * n)` - рецепт [grouper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (*"Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"*).

```
items = [5, 80, 3, 83, 1, 77, 1, 77, 2, 82, 1, 77, 5, 81, 2, 78, 1, 81, 5,
         85, 5, 85, 4, 84, 2, 78, 1, 81, 3, 83, 3, 78, 2, 82, 3, 83, 2, 78,
         5, 85, 5, 81, 2, 82, 4, 84]

CH_S = 2  # CHunk Size

l = ['_'.join(map(str, chunk)) for chunk in zip(*[iter(items)] * CH_S)]
```

Comment: Выглядит очень функционально :)